# NSOutlineView Selected Text Color Not Working in Swift

Tags: nsoutlineview, nstablecellview

*Swift 4, macOS 10.13*

I have an `NSOutlineView` and I'm trying to customize the look of each row when the user clicks it.

I have a view-based `NSTableCellView` subclass that I'm using for the cell. When I override `backgroundStyle`, **the icon change works perfectly**. But the text color is doing something weird.

**Here's a video to demonstrate:** http://d.pr/v/suTD8B

Here's my code:

```
class MenuItemCell: NSTableCellView{
  @IBOutlet weak var label: NSTextField!
  @IBOutlet weak var icon: NSImageView!

  //Customizes the selected state of menu row
  override var backgroundStyle: NSView.BackgroundStyle {
    set{
      if let rowView = self.superview as? NSTableRowView {
        super.backgroundStyle = rowView.isSelected ? .dark : .light
      }
      if self.backgroundStyle == .dark {
        label.textColor = NSColor.white
        icon.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "menu-project-selected"))
      }else{
        label.textColor = NSColor.menuTextColor
        icon.image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "menu-project"))
      }
    }
    get{ return super.backgroundStyle }
  }
}
```

Any idea what's wrong? I've been searching for hours and can't figure it out.

Comment: Where do you set self.backgroundStyle to dark? Next time you ask for it you return super.backgroundStyle with get.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this would never work reliably while the `NSOutlineView` **Highlight** was set to **Source List** in the storyboard editor. It was really unreliable.

Once I changed it to **Regular** then it worked fine.

[image]
[image]